# Prevent access to mobile photo library from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, file-io

I have an HTML5 based web application (not a mobile app) that uses input type="file" control for users to upload images. When accessed from on a mobile browser, my intent is to prevent users from accessing pictures in their camera library of their mobile phone.

I have run out of luck so thought will check in here to see if there are any options to prevent access to the mobile camera/photo library either through Javascript or any jquery libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">` But since its javascript the users can change it if they know how but for general use, use this.

Comment: Is it possible to go directly to a mobile app for eg: camscanner or google drive?

Comment: The problem is that your using javascript and javascript you can not trust the client. Even if its a mobile app you can still fake the camera.